# Compare Two Columns, Remove Duplicate Characters

Tags: sqlite

Example table:

```
  ID      CA      CB
  ------  ------  -----
  1       龍      龍 竜 龒
  2       齒      歯 齒 
  3       黽      黽
```

I would like to modify column CB so that it doesn't contain any of the characters in CA.
Like this:

```
  ID      CA      CB
  ------  ------  -----
  1       龍       竜 龒
  2       齒      歯 
  3       黽
```

(SQLite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean to remove the character of CA from CB **in the same row** and that there's always just one character in CA, you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET CB = REPLACE(CB, CA, '');
```

Comment: Thank you.
("Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.")